# How to correctly deploy my local trained tensorflow model to google cloud ai platform? I deployed it but no prediction image return

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I refer to this colab notebook to deploy my tf model and prediction in earthengine.[AI_platform_demo](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/AI_platform_demo.ipynb?authuser=2#scrollTo=hno8QSo-2XjQ)

I can successfully run this demo, but when I upload my local trained model and deploy it successfully, the folium map didn't show any prediction image.

What can I do to realize it? I don't know where is my problem.

Comment: You will have to understand first [UNET_regression_demo](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb) as the referenced example makes use of the previously created training data. You also need to check,  if the data points and types are the same as the created training data (as you are reusing the code from training data) or else it will just fail. You will have to update the training data code and prediction code to match your inputs.

Comment: Also, if you can share code, input data and output data as well as key points you updated from sample code for your scenario it will help us understand your issue. I would recommend first to check my previous comment.

Comment: thank you! But I don't use the traning data of this example notebook, I bother if it must use the google cloud to train a model so I can't use my local trained model.

Comment: I think you should check [training](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/overview) page about using your local trained model and submitting it to ai platform.